# Need to get or convert data from a site to be valid JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, rest

I am working on a script that will get data from a Website (Cisco Patches site) and based on the data received, I need to post it to another site (ServiceNow Event Management). The POST needs to be REST/JSON with specific keys for this to work.

I have enough code to GET the data and I have the code to POST working.

I am having a hard time with converting the data I get from GET to map it into valid JSON key value pairs to POST.

I am using the following code to get a list of new patches from Cisco website. I am getting the correct data but the format if the data is not how I can use it to post to another tool in JSON format (using different keys but values from the returned information.

This works -

```
def getjson(ciscourl):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(ciscourl)
    ciscodata = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(ciscodata)
```

The data I get back looks like below (this query resulted in 2 patches):

`[{"identifier":"cisco-sa-20180521-cpusidechannel","title":"CPU Side-Channel Information Disclosure Vulnerabilities: May 2018","version":"1.5","firstPublished":"2018-05-22T01:00:00.000+0000","lastPublished":"2018-05-31T20:44:16.123+0000","workflowStatus":null,"id":1,"name":"Cisco Security Advisory","url":"https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20180521-cpusidechannel","severity":"Medium","workarounds":"No","cwe":null,"cve":"CVE-2018-3639,CVE-2018-3640","ciscoBugId":"","status":"Updated","summary":"On May 21, 2018, researchers disclosed two vulnerabilities that take advantage of the implementation of speculative execution of instructions on many modern microprocessor architectures to perform side-channel information disclosure attacks. These vulnerabilities could allow an unprivileged, ","totalCount":6,"relatedResource":[]},{"identifier":"cisco-sa-20180516-firepwr-pb","title":"Cisco Firepower Threat Defense Software Policy Bypass Vulnerability","version":"1.0","firstPublished":"2018-05-16T16:00:00.000+0000","lastPublished":"2018-05-16T16:00:00.000+0000","workflowStatus":null,"id":1,"name":"Cisco Security Advisory","url":"https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20180516-firepwr-pb","severity":"Medium","workarounds":"No","cwe":"CWE-693","cve":"CVE-2018-0297","ciscoBugId":"CSCvg09316","status":"New","summary":"A vulnerability in the detection engine of Cisco Firepower Threat Defense software could allow an unauthenticated, remote attacker to bypass a configured Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) Access Control (AC) policy to block SSL traffic.The vulnerability is due to the incorrect handling ","totalCount":6,"relatedResource":[]}]`

I can extract values from this, as such `print(jarray.get('identifier'))` but I am having a hard time being able to map these values into my own JSON map with keys I define. So the value from the key `identifier` I got back, needs to map to a key called `"node"` in my JSON map.

I have tried `json.loads`, `json.load`, `json.dump`, `json.dumps`. Each time the error is Attribute Type error.

**This is the code where I am confused:**

```
def createJson(l):
#try:

    jsonarray = l
    o_source = "CiscoUpdatePatchChecker"
    o_node = (jsonarray.get('identifier')) #this does not work
    o_metric_name = ("Critical")
    o_type = ("test")
    o_resource = ("test_resource")
    o_description = jsonarray  #this works
    o_event_class = ("test event class")
    o_additional_info = jsonarray
    print ("-" * 50)
    print (o_source, o_node, o_metric_name, o_type, o_resource, o_description, o_event_class, o_additional_info)
    print ("-" * 50)
    data = {"source": o_source, "node": o_node, "metric_name": o_metric_name, "type": o_type, "resource": o_resource, "event_class": o_event_class, "description": o_description, "additional_info": o_additional_info}
    return json.dumps(data)
# except:
    #pass
```

Beyond this, the rest of the code just posts the data to ITSM which is working. -

```
def postjson(data):
    # try:
    url = posturl
    auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
    head = {'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'}
    payld = data
    ret = requests.post(url, auth=auth , data=payld, headers=head)
    # sys.stdout.write(ret.text)
    returned_data = ret.json()
    print(returned_data)
```

So my issue is to map data I am getting back to my keys:value pairs in a JSON map, & I will need to loop the code for as many times as the number of patches are retrieved. I am currently planning to loop in my main function for number of JSON maps that need to POST.

For now, I am just take all the data I get and mapping all the data I get to the `"description"` and `"additional_info"` field. This works and I can post the data fine.

It will help me tremendously if someone can point me to examples of how to manipulate the data I am getting from my GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json.loads(ciscodata)` returns an array of dictionaries.

The statement `o_node = (jsonarray.get('identifier'))` fails because it is trying to get a dictionary key when `jsonarray` is a list.

Try `o_node = jsonarray[0].get('identifier')`

I am not sure why you have parens around jsonarray -- those shouldn't be there.

In general, you can do something like:

```
for elem in jsonarray:
    identifier = elem.get('identifier')
    title = elem.get('title')
    ... etc
    do_something(identifier, title, ...)
```

This makes it easier to debug because you can test the values you get back from the api call.

If you are always getting the same keys in your dictionary, you can skip this assignment and just do

```
for elem in jsonarray:
    do_something(elem.get('key1'), elem.get('key2'), ...)`
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks! this is what I needed to move forward. I will now map the data from the dict into my key value pairs. The keys are always the same, so I will follow your 2nd example.